# new rlang error produces errors in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, rlang

A new error presented itself using a basic `dplyr::select` today:

```
library(tidyverse)
select(iris, starts_with("petal"))
```

returns

```
>Error in mut_env_parent(overscope$.top_env, lexical_env) : 
  object 'rlang_mut_env_parent' not found
```

My `sessionInfo`:

[image]

Comment: Works fine here

Comment: mising `)` at the end  `select(iris, starts_with("petal"))`

Comment: yes, I might expect the most widely used R package to work--as my question stated, it had been working here until this morning. 

I was instead hoping for someone to help me locate the source of _my_ error?

Comment: @Wen fixed, thanks, formatting mistake (not the source of the error message)

Comment: got it  , i try to search this type of error , but can not found it , BTW work as usual on my side,An alternative way to do this `df[,str_detect(names(df),'petal')]`

Comment: I got the same error message when I used `dplyr::select`, and I am also using `R 3.4.1`.

Comment: After I installed the developmental version from github of `dplyr` (`dplyr_0.7.2.9000`), the issue seems to be fixed. For people who encounter the same issue, try `devtools::install_github("hadley/dplyr")` to install the developmental version.

Comment: @ycw--fixed for me, thanks! if you want to make this the answer I'll confirm if for you.

Comment: Have been getting this same error in `mutate()` and their scoped variants as well. @ycw 's comment fixed my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For people who encountered the same problem, you could try to install the developmental version of `dplyr` (`dplyr_0.7.2.9000`). Based on the comments from others, at least some of us can fix this issue by doing this.

```
install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("hadley/dplyr")
```